# Create a DTM using the TIN algorithm

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to create a DTM on a county wide level (so using LAS catalog). The [lidRworkbook](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/dtm.html) advises to use a buffer when using the TIN method, however the workbook doesn't show how to do that. So how can I first create this `buffer`? And how can I then use this buffer to create a `dtm_tin`?

On a side note is there a way to directly store the DTM raster to disk rather than first the `rasterize_terrain` tool first saves the DTM to memory (who knows I might run out of memory) and then save it using the raster or terra package?

Code:

```
# Create a LAS catalog
LAS_List = readLAScatalog("path", recursive = TRUE)

# Create a DTM using the TIN method
dtm_tin = rasterize_terrain(LAS_List, res = 1, algorithm = tin())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to work with a LAScatalog is explained in [chap 14](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html). The buffer is explained in section [14.7.2](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html#engine-options-chunk-buffer).

The default is 50 m buffer so your code is already correct.

To store the raster on disk see section [14.8.2](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html#engine-dtm-ondisk). e.g

```r
opt_output_files(LAS_list) <-  paste0("folder/{*}_dtm")
```

The path must be templated to generate one file per chunk. This is not explicitely mentionned in [14.8.2](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html#engine-dtm-ondisk) but see `help("LAScatalog-class")`

> ### Output options
>
> The slot ⁠`@output_options`⁠ contains a `list` of options that determine how chunks (the sub-areas that are sequentially processed) are written. By "written" we mean written to files or written in R memory.
>
> `output_files`: string. If `output_files = ""` outputs are returned in R. Otherwise, if `output_files` is a string the outputs will be written to files. This is useful if the output is too big to be returned in R. A path to a filename template without a file extension (the engine guesses it for you) is expected. When several files are going to be written a single string is provided with a template that is automatically filled. For example, the following file names are possible:
>
> `"/home/user/als/normalized/file_{ID}_segmented"`
> `"C:/user/document/als/zone52_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}_confidential"`
> `"C:/user/document/als/{ORIGINALFILNAME}_normalized"`
> This option will generate as many filenames as needed with custom names for each file. The allowed templates are `{XLEFT}`, `{XRIGHT}`, `{YBOTTOM}`, `{YTOP}`, `{ID}`, `{XCENTER}`, `{YCENTER}`, `{ORIGNALFILENAME}`. See `opt_output_files`.

Comment: Awesome, but I am still a bit confused, do I need to first run `opt_output_files(LAS_list) <-  paste0("folder/{*}_dtm")` and then run `rasterize_terrain` which will automatically save the `DTM raster`  to the disk path defined using  `opt_output_files`?

Comment: So I first ran `pt_output_files(LAS_List) =  paste0("O:/folder/filename_dtm")` and then I ran `dtm_tin = rasterize_terrain(BC_LAS_List, res = 1, algorithm = tin())`. First thing I noticed was that the memory was still being used up. Also a little later  I got this error:  error occurred when processing the chunk 2. Try to load this chunk with:
 `chunk <- readRDS("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeoYno9/chunk2.rds")
 las <- readLAS(chunk)
[writeRaster] file exists. You can use overwrite=TRUE to overwrite it`

Comment: Your path is not templated. See my edited anwser

Comment: So I ran `opt_output_files(BC_LAS_List) =  paste0("O:/LiDAR_Tree_Points/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_dtm")` thinking that the function will pickup the original filename from LAS file and put `_dtm` next to it to save the `DTM` raster file. But instead I got this error `Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'ORIGNALFILENAME' not found`.

Comment: So now I am running `opt_output_files(BC_LAS_List) =  paste0("O:/LiDAR_Tree_Points/{}_dtm")`. Idk if this is correct or not, but it is running, however I am noticing the memory use going up.

Comment: There is nothing in `{}` I'm surprised it does not crash, fails or whatever. Anyway it won't work.

Comment: Yup it failed after a while so what template should I use so that the function automatically picks up each LAS file's `filename` and adds `_dtm` to it while saving its `DTM raster` to file?

Comment: `{ORIGNALFILENAME}`.  Or `{*}` is understood and maybe `*` is understood as well.